# python lambda expression with dynamic fields

Tags: python, lambda, filter

I have a list of dictionaries. I want to be able to filter this list with a dynamic list of fields. So that;

```
my_list = [{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}, {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2}]
reference_row = {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}

compare_fields = ['a'] # Compares only field 'a' of reference row with rows in my_list 
# Magical filter expression results in [{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}, {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2}]

compare_fields = ['a', 'b'] # Compares fields 'a' and 'b' of reference row with rows in my_list 
# Magical filter expression results in [{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}, {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}]

compare_fields = ['a', 'b', 'c'] # Compares fields 'a', 'b' and 'c' of reference row with rows in my_list 
# Magical filter expression results in [{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}]
```

I've tried something like the following but it did not work:

```
list(filter(lambda d: (d[field] == reference_row[field] for field in compare_fields ), my_list))
```

I do not want to go over the items in compare_fields and filter by one field in each iteration. Any neat way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `all` function which is only true if every element of an iterable is True. Otherwise every input to your filter was returning `True`.

```
list(filter(lambda d: all(d[field] == reference_row[field] for field in compare_fields), my_list))
```

---

I think this is a little cleaner

```
[d for d in my_list if 
 all(d[field] == reference_row[field] for field in compare_fields)]
```